# Kotlin gives multiple "unresolved reference" errors in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I try to follow developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text#displaying-text and get

```
Unresolved reference: remember
Unresolved reference: mutableStateOf
Unresolved reference: OutlinedTextField
Unresolved reference: it
```

What am I doing wrong?

The whole function:

```
@Composable
fun SimpleOutlinedTextFieldSample() {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    OutlinedTextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { text = it },
        label = { Text("Label") }
    )
}
```

Imports:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.kotlinprojectapp.ui.theme.KotlinProjectAppTheme
```

Comment: could you please show your imports

Comment: Updated it in the OP post

Comment: You haven't imported those properties/objects.

Comment: Put your cursor on each of the errors, hit Alt + Enter (or click the lightbulb) and it will offer to import them for you. Watch how your imports change - you're importing the parent package for those classes/functions, not the class/function itself, that's why it has no idea what a ``remember`` is etc. (Leave the ``it`` one until last, that should fix itself once Android Studio knows what's going on with the rest of it)

Comment: You are right @cactustictacs, but e.g. if I add Color import it is then doesn't understand the color itselft and gives me ```Unresolved reference: LightGray```

Comment: If you want to just say ``LightGray`` then you need to import ``androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color.LightGray`` - that way it will know what you're referencing. Most examples will just import the ``Color`` package (i.e. ``import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color``) meaning you have to reference your colour as ``Color.LightGray`` - it knows what ``Color`` is (you imported it), and then it can look up ``LightGray`` on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct imports:

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.material.OutlinedTextField
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
```